# How to center GIF in Live Wallpaper

Tags: java, android

I am making a live wallpaper with a gif image that is put in the raw directory, how can I put the gif in the center of the screen, no matter what device I am using?? I understand why my code right now puts it in the left, because display.getWidth-display.getWidth =0, and same with height, hence (0,0) is in the top left. But what is center?! I cannot seem to figure it out for the life of me. This class is extending WallpaperService.

```
@Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);


        mScaleX = width / (1.5f*mNyan.width());
        mScaleY = height / (1.5f*mNyan.height());
        Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        mWidth = (display.getWidth()-display.getWidth());
        mHeight = (display.getHeight()-display.getHeight());





        nyan();
    }
```

and this is the end where I draw the canvas...

```
void nyanNyan(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(mScaleX, mScaleY);
        mNyan.setTime(mWhen);
        mNyan.draw(canvas, mWidth,mHeight);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

Can anyone help!?! I'm stuck, and I can't move past this. I also tried, without any luck:

```
void nyanNyan(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(mScaleX, mScaleY);
        mNyan.setTime(mWhen);
        mNyan.draw(canvas, mCenterX - mNyan.width() , mCenterY - mNyan.height());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I do not fully understand your code (e.g. where vars like `mCenterX` are coming from or how they are defined) I can not gurantee the code to run properly without further adjustments.

Assuming that you have access to nyan's width and height (I'll call it `nyan.getWidth()`) and the canvas' dimensions, then your last `mNyan.draw()` call should probably look like this:

```
mNyan.draw(
    canvas,
    ( canvas.getWidth() - nyan.getWidth() ) / 2,
    ( canvas.getHeight() - nyan.getHeight() ) / 2
);
```